# Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed

Tags: xubuntu, java, packaging, jdk, oracle

Recently I installed `jdk1.8.0_51` on my Xubuntu OS, and now I need to install `ant` for `pyhton-for-android` package, but after running the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

I get the following error :

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also followed the instructions about reinstalling `oracle-java7-installer` but they didn't worked.Is there any problem with my java installation or may package manager?

Answer (score 0):

Is JDK 8 required? I tend to get mostly everything to work with `openjdk-7-jdk` But then again, I have never worked with `ant` or `python-for-android`.